# Service event_subscribe before path_processor_inbound

Tags: 8, symfony-services

I have ha service with tag: event_subscribe (KernelEvents::REQUEST) with priority 30 and in the same module a service path_processor_inbound with priority 29

The problem is: in event_subscribe Service creo a Constant but the service path_processor_inbound is called before.
I tried all the variants of priority, but it is not the problem.

Comment: _in event_subscribe Service creo a Constant but the service path_processor_inbound is called before_ 29 comes before 30 so that's right isn't it?

Comment: No, i want call first event_subscribe

Comment: Please edit your question, it currently says the opposite

Comment: ! U undestand priority ?
"The priority value is optional and defaults to 0. The higher the priority, the sooner it gets executed."

Comment: Oh I see, Symfony and Drupal have different definitions of "priority". In Drupal's API, a lower number means a higher priority; a numerical running order if you will. I'd post your code and describe the methods you're using to confirm the priority is being set properly etc

Comment: Now i try: (same problem)

module_event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\country\EventSubscriber\ValidateCountry
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber,  priority: 20 }

  module_subscriber.path_processor:
    class: Drupal\country\PathProcessor\OutboundPathProcessor
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 30 }
      - { name: path_processor_outbound, priority: 30 }

Comment: I didn't explain that very well - I was just explaining that Drupal's API does things one way and Symfony's another. You're dealing with Symfony's API here so the way you originally had it was correct, the problem must be elsewhere

Comment: ! my serivice.yml is correct, priority is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both priorities are for different queues. If you set a priority for an event subscriber this is only for the specific event you subscribe to. In this example you subscribe to KernelEvents::REQUEST. Then you can only move up and down in the list of all other subscribers to this event.

You can find more information and a list of the D8 events here:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/events/8.2.x

Path inbound/outbound processors are not even events. These are handled by the [PathProcessor Manager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!PathProcessor!PathProcessorManager.php/class/PathProcessorManager/8.2.x) and the priority set here is again only for the list of all other path processors.

Comment: ! can retrive a list with queque priority ?

Comment: I've checked, path processors are called dependent on the status of your cache and what module you've installed 5 or 10 times per request. So there is no single event you can target. But you can try to increase the priority for the KernelEvents:REQUEST subscriber until  you have the result you want.

Comment: There is a great debugging tool from Symfony, Web Profiler. In Drupal this is included in the Devel module.

Comment: ! when path_processor don't have a queue specific ?

Comment: ! 30000000 priority, same problem. It's not a prority problem